# What's the return type of a LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

Is it `IEnumerable<T>`. As far as I know, the reference always points to a class instance. What instance type does the LINQ query really point to?

Comment: Why closing the question? It teaches good programming practices (by showing what you must not depend on: implementation)

Comment: It depends on what the LINQ query is.

Comment: I'd say we need the motivation behind this question to be able to adequately answer it.

Answer (score 18):

**You can find it out by calling `.GetType()`** on your `IEnumerable<T>` variable and inspecting the type in the debugger.

For different LINQ providers and even different LINQ methods, such types may or may not be different.

What matters to your code is that they all implement `IEnumerable<T>` which you should work with, or `IQueryable<T>` which also accepts *expressions*, meaning your predicates and projections will become syntax trees and may be manipulated by a LINQ provider at runtime, e.g. to be translated into SQL.

**Actual** classes, if this is what you're asking about, may even be compiler-generated, e.g. `yield return` expression is translated to such a class.
Either way, **they are usually internal and you should never, *ever* depend on them**.

Answer (score 10):

Depending on your original data source, it is either IEnumerable or IQueryable:

The result of a Linq database query is typically [IQueryable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb351562.aspx) which is derived from IEnumerable<T>, IQueryable, and IEnumerable.

If your database query includes an OrderBy clause, the type is [IOrderedQueryable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb340178.aspx), being derived from IQueryable<T>

If your data source is an IEnumerable, the result type is [IEnumerable<T>](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9eekhta0.aspx)

Comment: I think he means *actual* classes, not the interface.

Comment: I was just wondering the same thing. I guess there can be only one right answer (in his mind) for a question that can actually have multiple answers depending on how you interpret it. Btw I like your answer best so far! Lets see what the OP had in mind.

Comment: @Maverik: I voted down both your and @Soul Reaver's answers because they are *not useful*, which is what downvote button is supposed to represent.  The reason I consider them to be not useful is because OP asks about 'instance type', as opposed to interface, which leads me to conclusion he means *class types*. Neither `IQueryable<>/IOrderedQueryable<>/IEnumerable<>` are correct answers because **they are interfaces, and OP clearly indicated he knows interface types himself**. In this sense I believe @helios and my answers are correct, because they answer the OP's question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know but I guess it's an internal type. You don't have to think about the class.

In fact it could be different classes depending on the concrete query. The compiler could convert the LINQ expression to one or another implementation depending on the conditions/processing.

Answer (score 0):

if I am not mistaken, `IEnumerable< T >`, where T depends on your query

Comment: I guess he wants to know the concrete class, not the interface. Of course it's irrelevant (and it can be different for each concrete query)

Answer (score -1):

You can check [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb397906.aspx) for  Three parts of Query operation.You can see that the return type of an LINQ query is IEnumerable< int >.

Comment: I feel like this is wrong on most levels. And includes an external reference without really answering the question...