# optimise code into linq expression

Tags: c#, linq

I have an observable collection I want to remove an element from.  I have tried using the linq .Where syntax but i am getting stuck with the casting.

```
public class Atc
{
    public string Code { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public string ParentDescriptions { get; set; }
}
```

i have defined the observable collection of medicines,

```
public ObservableCollection<Atc> MedicinesObservableCollection
```

and i have a method to filter out the item from the collection that works:

```
private void RemoveMedicineListItem(string code)
{
    var filteredCollection = new ObservableCollection<Atc>();
    foreach (var item in MedicinesObservableCollection)
    {
        if (item.Code != code)
        {
            filteredCollection.Add(item);
        }
    }
    MedicinesObservableCollection = filteredCollection; 
}
```

I have tried:

```
(ObservableCollection<Atc>)MedicinesObservableCollection.Where(x => x.Code != code);
```

but this gets a runtime exception
System.InvalidCastException: 'Unable to cast object of type 'WhereEnumerableIterator1[Atc]' to type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ObservableCollection1[Atc]'.'

i get this is something to do with the linq enumerables but i am out of my depth.

Comment: Use constructor: [`new ObservableCollection<T>(IEnumerable<T>)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc679169(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All the answers are correct but when using `ObservableCollection` it would be better to do a remove on the same object rather then creating a new list.

```
MedicinesObservableCollection.Remove(MedicinesObservableCollection.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Code == code));
```

This is because recreating the collection might force all the items in the list to be re-rendered and this way only one item will be removed from the same collection.

Answer (score 4):

You can´t *cast* an instance of `WhereIterator<Atc>` (which your `Where`-clause actually returns) to `ObservableCollection<Atc>)`. The returned instance only implements `IEnumerable<Atc>`, this is you can *iterate* it. However it doesn´t havy *anything* in common with any list, or in particular with an *observable* one.

However you can *create* a new one based on the returned value:

```
var result = new ObservableCollection(MedicinesObservableCollection.Where(x => x.Code != code));
```

Answer (score 1):

Linq doesn't return a collection of the same type as the input. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6262595/whats-the-return-type-of-a-linq-query). So your cast to `ObservableCollection<Atc>` fails as it's some internal implementation of `IEnumerable`, not an `ObservableCollection`.

The solution is just to create a new [ObservableCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
var items = new ObservableCollection<Atc>(MedicinesObservableCollection.Where(x => x.Code != code));
```